# flutter doctor shows an error in PowerShell

Tags: flutter, dart

When I typed `flutter doctor` in PowerShell, it shows an error. How can I fix it?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Acer> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
PS C:\Users\Acer>
```

Comment: Can you say something about what you have done until now and, if you are following some guide, give a link to that guide? Also, have you tried to do what the command says? Like e.g.run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows  this is the link

Comment: I have just started to learn flutter using android studio

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for the Android Studio Setup: [Set up an editor](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor)

For the licenses just type `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and press enter like @julemand101 said, then just accept all the licenses in your Terminal

The last warning can be ignored for now since you will probably start an Emulator later.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you 